# Equi Join 2 different files on a common field using mapreduce

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, mapreduce

I have recently started learning hadoop/mapreduce/java.I am working on the below assignment.

We have 2 input files.

File1 has 2 fields. Airlineid and number of routes.(airlineid is unique)
File2 has 4 fields. Airlineid,airline name,country.(airlineid is unique)

And I need to find out the most active airlines countrywise.
i.e - For each country I need to find the airline with highest number of routes.

Let me explain it with an example.Let's say

File1 has the following contents.

```
airlineid1  10

airlineid2  20

airlineid3  30
```

File2 has the following contents

```
airlineid1 airlinename1 country1

airlineid2 airlinename2 country1

airlineid5 airlinename5 country1
```

The output should be

```
country1 airlineid2 airlinename2 20
```

I've written 2 mapreduce codes for this.

1. JoinReduce - does a reduce side join on both files on airlineid.
2. Activeairline - calculates the most active airline countrywise by using the output created in program 1.

I am getting **arrayindexoutofbound: 4** error while running program 2.I think it's because the output file created in program one didn't do equijoin.So it has some records which don't have the count field.(airlineid only present in file 2).When I am trying to assign count for those records it's giving arrayindexoutofbound option.

As I mentioned earlier I am new to Java and I am not sure how to handle this.
Could anyone please help!

Below are my 2 programs

### Program1(Joinreduce)

```
public class JoinReduce {

  public static class RoutesMapper
   extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  String airlineid = itr.nextToken();
  String count = itr.nextToken();

    context.write(new Text(airlineid), new Text("routes" + "\t" + count));
   }
 }

 public static class AirlinesMapper
  extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{


 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
           ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  String record = value.toString();
  String[] parts = record.split(",");
  String airlineid =  parts[0];
  String airlinename = parts[1];
  String country = parts[6];

  if(airlinename.length()==0){
        airlinename="NA";
   }
  if(country.length()==0){
        country="NA";
  }
   context.write(new Text(airlineid),new Text("airlines"+ "\t" + airlineid +   "\t" + airlinename + "\t" + country));  
  }
}

 public static class JoinReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  String airlineid ="";
  String count = "";    
  String name = "";
  String country = "";
  for (Text val : values) {
      String parts[] = val.toString().split("\t");
      if (parts[0].equals("routes")){
         count = parts[1]; 
      }else if (parts[0].equals("airlines")){  
        airlineid = parts[1];  
        name = parts[2] ;
        country = parts[3];
      }
  }

  context.write(new Text("Joinedfile"), new Text(airlineid + "\t" + name +  "\t" + country + "\t" + count));
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "Join Reduce");
job.setJarByClass(JoinReduce.class);
job.setReducerClass(JoinReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),
              TextInputFormat.class,RoutesMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),
              TextInputFormat.class,AirlinesMapper.class);
   Path outputPath = new Path(args[2]);               
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

### Program2(activeairline)

```
public class Activeairline {

  public static class ActiveMapper
       extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{


    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String record = value.toString();
        String parts[] = record.split("\t");

        String airlineid = parts[1];
        String name = parts[2];
        String country = parts[3];
        if(!(parts[4].length()==0)){

          String count = parts[4];           
          context.write(new Text(country),new Text(airlineid + "\t" + name + "\t" + count));
      }
     }
    } 



public static class ActiveReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  int max = 0;
  String maxairlineid = "";
  String maxname = "";
  for (Text val : values) {
    String parts[] = val.toString().split("\t");
    int count = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    String airlineid = parts[0];
    String name = parts[1];
    if (count > max){
        max = count;
        maxairlineid = airlineid;
        maxname = name;                 
    } 
  }
  context.write(key, new Text("Most Active airline " + "\t" + maxname + "\t" + maxairlineid));
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "Active airline");
job.setJarByClass(Activeairline.class);
job.setMapperClass(ActiveMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(ActiveReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: Look at your input if there are five words in your line seprated by tab. `String record = value.toString();
        String parts[] = record.split("\t");`

Comment: For some records it doesn't have the 5th field count.But for some records it's there.How do I handle this?

Comment: check for length and dont process that record...

Comment: @ SMA I modified the code like below.But still getting the same arrayindexboundexception :4 error                                                                   if(!(parts[4].length()==0)){      
      String count = parts[4];      
   context.write(new Text(country),new Text(airlineid + "\t" + name + "\t" + count));
      }

Comment: your code should be `if (parts.length > 4) then access parts[4]`

Comment: The above change worked!! Thanks